# Unity.Mvc - UnityDependencyResolver issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Current project is an Mvc4 application, I had Ioc working and recently it just stopped.

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(New UnityDependencyResolver(RegisterIocServices()))
```

That line was working, and now I am getting the following error:

> ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
>
> The type Unity.Mvc3.UnityDependencyResolver does not appear to
>   implement Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator.
>   Parameter name: commonServiceLocator

Anybody experiencing this? Any thoughts or advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More than likely, you're missing a Using somewhere, or possibly a reference.

Comment: I uninstalled the Unity.Mvc NuGet package, then reinstalled it and it seemed to resolve the issue. So you're probably right. Really strange behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling/reinstalling the Unity MVC package did not resolve the issue. I ended up having to put a hard reference in the project to the Microsoft.EnterpriseLibrary.Common library and that seemed to clear it up for a week or two.
I then started seeing the error reappear intermittently, doing a full solution clean and build resolved it once in awhile. It would work, then all of a sudden revert to the error message.

So I finally gave up on Unity.Mvc this morning and implemented Autofac instead. Once I set up my bootstrapper file for Autofac, it worked on the first compile and has been stable all morning.

Here is the boostrapper file for Autofac in case anyone needs a sample. NOTE: I use WebActivator to get all of my bootsrapping classes to run pre-startup instead of putting a bunch of code in the Global.asax.vb file.

```
#Region "Imports"

Imports System.Reflection
Imports Autofac
Imports Autofac.Integration.Mvc
Imports MyCompany.Data.Repositories
Imports MyCompany.Services
Imports MyCompany.Web.Mvc.Public.Bootstrap
Imports MyCompany.Web.Mvc.Public.Services

#End Region

#Region "Assembly Meta"

' This tells the app to run the "Start" method prior to running the App_Start method in Global.asax
<Assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(GetType(AutofacDI), "Initialize")> 

#End Region

Namespace MyCompany.Web.Mvc.Public.Bootstrap

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Class to setup dependency injection and register types/services.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public NotInheritable Class AutofacDI

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Method to register the Unity dependency injection component.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks>
        ''' This line of code below could alternatively be placed in Global.asax App_Start(), doing
        ''' so in this manner ensures that this gets run "PreStart".
        ''' </remarks>
        Public Shared Sub Initialize()

            ' Create Unity dependency container.
            Dim dependencyContainer = BuildIocContainer()

            ' Set DI resolver
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(New AutofacDependencyResolver(dependencyContainer))

        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Registers the IOC types/services.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <returns></returns>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        Private Shared Function BuildIocContainer() As Autofac.IContainer

            Dim builder = New ContainerBuilder

            With builder
                ' Register Controllers
                .RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())

                ' Custom MyCompany/Mvc objects
                .RegisterType(Of FormsAuthenticationService)().As(Of IFormsAuthenticationService)().InstancePerHttpRequest()
                .RegisterType(Of AccountMembershipService)().As(Of IMembershipService)().InstancePerHttpRequest()

                '***************************************************************
                '*  MyCompany service objects.
                '***************************************************************
                ' This is auto registration, it replaces all the individual registration lines of code below.
                builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(GetType(CatalogCodeService).Assembly).
                    Where(Function(t) t.Name.EndsWith("Service")).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerHttpRequest()

                '***************************************************************
                '*  MyCompany repository objects (used by service objects above)
                '***************************************************************
                ' This is auto registration, it replaces all the individual registration lines of code below.
                builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(GetType(CatalogCodeRepository).Assembly).
                    Where(Function(t) t.Name.EndsWith("Repository")).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerHttpRequest()
            End With

            Return builder.Build()

        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Answer (score 3):

with MVC 4.0

The problem I had was IDependencyResolver has two version

```
 //using System.Web.Http.Dependencies;  //wrong version for me

 using System.Web.Mvc; //correct version for me.
```

using System.Web.Mvc was the version that I needed with my Web API project.

I'm using unity but the blog post below help me get straight on the problem.

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/using-ninject-with-the-latest-asp-net-web-api-source/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Nick. I ended up switching my DI over to AutoFac instead of Unity.

Answer (score 0):

While not an answer to this specific question, I was also receiving the above error message, and this question is the first hit when Googling for that message. I had this problem because I stupidly inherited from `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver` instead if just implementing the interface, eg:

```
// wrong
public class MyDependencyResolver : System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver
{ ... }

// correct
public class MyDependencyResolver : System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver
{ ... }
```

It took me a while to work this out, so I hope this saves someone else the trouble.